# Purpose of ICs in EMCA - Type-C

Tags: usb-c, usb-pd

I can't find the purpose of IC ( which is power sourced by VConn) inside the EMCA. 
Source/Sink can communicate with EMCA via this IC. But what is exactly function of this IC in Power Delivery ?

P/S: IC means : Integrated Circuit inside EMCA( Electronics Mark Cable Assembly - a type of cable which complies with Type-C connector). This IC is powered by Vconn signal.

Thank you!

Comment: Please try to make it easy for people to answer your question by giving some context. Are you talking about a USB-C cable? Which IC? Do you have any links at all?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some links.

Comment: Have you tried searching "Electronically Marked Cable Assemblies" on your favorite search engine? I think you will find some helpful results.

Comment: Oh...I found it, thank you very much for your guidance. I will add the answer for anyone , who need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my question:
[Do all USB Type C cables support full power delivery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/187900/do-all-usb-type-c-cables-support-full-power-delivery/213789#213789)

> In order for a USB-PD compliant source to advertise capabilities
>   greater than 3A (or up to the full 5A limit of the spec) the Type-C
>   cable must be an Electronically Marked Cable Assembly (EMCA) and
>   support SOP' packets. It must respond to the "Discover Identity" VDM
>   sequence (USB-PD spec section 6.4.4.3.1) with a cable VDO packet with
>   bits 6..5 set to indicate 5A current handling capability.